# Use an instance of Orion Context Broker FIWare

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

It is my first time with Fiware technologies and I want to test an instance of the FI-PPP Testbed for Orion Context Broker. I have the service end point (http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/configuration-manager-orion-context-broker/instances) but I don't know how I can use this information. I'm calling the service through REST Console Chrome extension and I don't have any response useful.

What are the steps to test Orion Context Broker through the instance from http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers ??

**UPDATE:** 
I'm reading https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers and I don't have clear if I need to install a Linux machine or  I need to use a Virtual Machine from Fi-Lab.

Could anybody help me???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recomend you to use the Configuration Manager catalogue entry except if you have a powerful reason to do that. Use [Publish/Subscribe Broker entry](http://catalogue.fi-ware.org/enablers/publishsubscribe-context-broker-orion-context-broker) instead (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401501/orions-configuration-manager-vs-pubsub-broker) about differences between Configuration Manager and Publish/Subscribe Broker).

Taking into account that, the Orion Context Broker instance that you should use is the one at
**orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026**. You need an authentication token to use it, a simple way of getting that token is described in [the Orion Quick Start Guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Quick_Start_for_Programmers).

Comment: Thanks you @fgalan, I take into account your response!!

Comment: Last comment is not actually related with the topic with this question. Please, introduce new topics in separate questions. Anyway, it seems accessing to VM aspects are covered in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345226/accesing-to-a-vm-on-fi-lab